# Elasticsearch: get documents only when value changes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index with such kind of documents:

```
from_1,to_1,timestamp_1
from_1,to_1,timestamp_2
from_1,to_2,timestamp_3
from_2,to_3,timestamp_4
from_1,to_2,timestamp_5
from_2,to_3,timestamp_6
from_1,to_1,timestamp_7
from_2,to_4,timestamp_8
```

I need a query that would return a document only if its combination of `from` and `to` values is different than the previous seen document with the same `from` value.

So with the provided sample above:

1. document with `timestamp_1` should be in the result because there is no earlier document with `from_1`+`to_1` combination
2. document with `timestamp_2` must be skipped because its `from`+`to` combination is exactly the same as the last seen document with `from` = `from_1`
3. document with `timestamp_3` should be in the result because its `to` field (`to_2`) is different than the value of the last seen with the same `from` (`to_1` in document with `timestamp_1`
4. document with `timestamp_4` should be in the result
5. document with `timestamp_5` must not be in the result because it has the same combination of from+to as the last seen with `from_1` (document with `timestamp_3`)
6. document with `timestamp_6` must not be in the result because it has the same combination of from+to as the last seen with `from_2` (document with `timestamp_4`)
7. document with `timestamp_7` should be in the result because it has the different combination of from+to to the last seen with `from_1` (document with `timestamp_3`)
8. document with `timestamp_8` should be in the result because its combination is completely new so far

I need to fetch all such "semi-unique" documents from the index, so it would be nice if it possible to use `scroll` request or `after_key` if an aggregation is used.

Any ideas how to approach it?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could come up with is the following (let me know if it does not work with your data).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "from_and_to": {
      "composite" : {
        "size": 5,
        "sources": [
          {
            "from_to_collected":{
              "terms": {
                "script": {
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "source": "doc['from'].value + '_' + doc['to'].value"
                }
              }
            }
          }]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_from_and_to_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"timestamp":{"order":"asc"}}],
            "_source": {"includes": ["_id"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `terms` [aggregations is probabilistic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts).

This will allow you to scroll to the next set of buckets over the `from_to_collected` key.